# How to pack two bytes array in python and write/read from file

Tags: python, struct, memoryview

Supposing say I have key and value in bytes format. I need to write to this information to file and then read it back for replaying. Easiest way is to write the len(key)|key|len(value)|value so on so forth.  Im trying to write this logic using python memoryview and struct.

pack_into  in struct module only accepts the input as integers.

```
import sys
from struct import *
from ctypes import *

buf = create_string_buffer(16)
key = b'<some data in hex>'
value = b'<some data in hex>
pack_into("@QQ",buf,0,key,value)
struct.error: required argument is not an integer
```

Im unable to find a solution to this problem. kindly help me out with solution.

Comment: The Q formatting character means that you want to pack a python integer as a C unsigned longlong integer. This is very different from <some data in hex>. Can you provide data examples ?

Comment: Consider the key is bytes format key=b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08' and value is also in bytes b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08' of length 9268 (it may vary). Now im trying to write these contents to file and need to read the same contents replay in kafka. Im aware of reading and writing of file in bytes format. Im not able to get the picture how to set the offsets ?

Comment: What does "replay in kafka" mean?

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps simply `pickle.dump()` the `(key, value)` tuple. and read it back with `pickle.load()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ctypes` or `struct` for this. Just open the file in binary mode and then you can write & read the bytes directly.

Demo:

```
key = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08'
val = b'\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
print(key, val)

fname = 'test.dat'
with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(key + val)

with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    key = f.read(8)
    val = f.read(8)

print(key, val)
```

**output**

```
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08' b'\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08' b'\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
```

**hexdump of test.dat**

```
00000000  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08  f8 f9 fa fb fc fd fe ff  |................|
00000010
```

Comment: this will only work if the key and value are of fixed length. The solution is for this answer is write in length(key) | key | length(value) | value.

Comment: Im trying write a logic using file input output f.seek(offset, from_what). There should some better way to solve problem using struct and memoryview.

Comment: @user128956 Sorry, I don't understand your second comment.